# Calling SharePoint on premise rest api from online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

How to call sharepoint onpremise rest api from sharepoint online ?
So i want to call user profile data of current user from sharepoint on premise but want to display data in SharePoint online both environment are using same credentials

Comment: Could you please share the API endpoint you're trying to call? If you want to get user profile data of current user is - `http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties` and this API can be called from SharePoint On-Premise and Online as well. Can you tell me what's the solution type from where you're calling the API.

Comment: my issue is that i am trying cross domain call which is blocked by cors so trying to call this api from online but my endpoints are for onprem

Comment: If you're facing the CORS policy issue then you can go for either of these options. First, You can write a MS flow of HTTP request received trigger and in the flow call the endpoint which is having the CORS issue. Or secondly, You can write an Azure Function to call the CORS issue endpoint through C# libraries. In both cases, you'll get a URL to call from SharePoint Online which works as bridge to call the API without CORS issue.